# C# Math.Round very long double - not working

Tags: c#, double, long-integer

here is what I'm trying to do:

```
double result = Math.Pow((1 + 8), 60) - 1;
```

And the result variable is: 
        **1.7970102999144311E+57**  double

And trying to:

```
Math.Round(result, 5);
```

Returns same : **1.7970102999144311E+57**   double
I'd like to round it to **1.79701**   for example

Any solutions ?

Comment: Round rounds a number to an integer. What you want us significant figures, not rounding.

Comment: @WaiHaLee `Math.Round` only rounds to an integer if you use the overload `Math.Round(value)` without passing digits. Otherwise, it definitely *does not* round to an integer - it rounds to the specified number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what you're seeing.

```
1.7970102999144311E+57
```

Is scientific notation for

```
1797010299914431100000... (with 41 trailing zeros).
```

It is a whole number, thus rounding it to 5 decimal places will correctly return the same value.

What you want to do is format the output of the number

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.#####E+0}", result);
```

Which returns `1.79701E+57`. Note that this is a *very* different number from `1.79701`

Comment: I guess I'm not very familiar with this scientific notations, in the first moment it looked to me as a decimal number, but as I'm looking on the number again you seems correct about it. Now it's clear to me, and I know what have to do next with that numbers, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that Math.Round rounds things to the right of the decimal point.  For example if you're dealing with currency and you perform an operation that leaves you with $1.5234524, you would use:

```
Math.Round(1.5234524,2);
// output 1.52
```

The number you're dealing with is actually scientific notation for a very large number with nothing to the right of the decimal point.  This is why the result of Math.Round is the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

The earlier comments and answers are correct. But to get what you are trying to achieve you can use the following:

```
double result = Math.Pow((1 + 8), 60) - 1;
string s = String.Format("{0:E5}", result);
double d = Double.Parse(s);
```

Comment: Still the result is: 1.79701E+57  !? Any idea how can I get rid of this useless ( in my case) scientific notation ?

Comment: `string s = String.Format("{0:E5}", result).Substring(0,7);`

Comment: a little bit "dirty" solution, but still works, thank you @Clay Ver Valen

Comment: Oh, I completely agree, but given that the number you are try to get to is entirely different from the mathematical answer I figured "dirty" was on the table. :-)

Comment: @the_root Are you sure scientific notation is useless in your case? Do you really want 1797010299914431055401678994746813871720176674767798009856 as output?